# Displaying array of items on a textview

Tags: android, for-loop, textview, runnable

I need to display many String values from an Array in a TextView. I am using Runnable for this. But it runs only once! If I put a for loop the code throws error.

```
Runnable hMyTimeTask = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        nCounter++;
        label.setText(rates[nCounter]);
    }
};

try {
    handler.removeCallbacks(hMyTimeTask);
    handler.postDelayed(hMyTimeTask, 1000); // delay 1 second
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Using a for loop:

```
Runnable hMyTimeTask = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        for (int i = 0; i < rates.length; i++) {
            label.setText(rates[i]);
        }
    }
};

try {
    handler.removeCallbacks(hMyTimeTask);
    handler.postDelayed(hMyTimeTask, 1000); // delay 1 second
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am using runnable for this. but it runs only once!

Inside your Runnable you need to post your Runnable again to repeat it:

```
Runnable hMyTimeTask = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        nCounter++;
        if(nCounter >= rates.length)
            nCounter = 0;
        label.setText(rates[nCounter]);

        // Run this again
        handler.postDelayed(this, 1000); // delay 1 second
    }
};
```

Comment: i think OP is calling `handler.removeCallbacks` that's why it's running only once. OP need to put some condition before calling `removeCallbacks`

Comment: It could be, the formatting is horrible. To me, it looks like that try-catch block is somewhere else outside the Runnable...

Comment: I need to print one string at a time. I have stored these strings in an array of type String.

Comment: @user2195062 : you just need to put if condition before calling `handler.removeCallbacks` as `if(nCounter>rates.length){handler.removeCallbacks(hMyTimeTask);}else{nCounter++;}` inside Runnable instead of outside Runnable

Comment: @user2195062 I updated my answer, this will display one String each second until you call `removeCallback()`.